# Connect to the unix-socket using bash

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, sockets

I have a simple server in cpp that just listening a socket and prints received data.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int sock, listener;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes_read;

    listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(listener < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(3210);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(2);
    }

    listen(listener, 1);
    
    while(1)
    {
        sock = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
        if(sock < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(3);
        }

        while(1)
        {
            bytes_read = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);
            if(bytes_read <= 0) break;
            printf(buf);
            send(sock, buf, bytes_read, 0);
        }
    
        close(sock);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I need to connect to the server's socket with bash (without using of some another utilities) and send some message.

I tried to write a script. It looks like that:

```
 exec 4</dev/tcp/0.0.0.0/3210
 echo -ne "Message" >&4
```

But it's not working.

There're output of the `ss -t -a` command

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port  Process 

LISTEN     0      1            0.0.0.0:3210               0.0.0.0:*
```

So, what shall I do to connect to the server's socket using "clear" bash and send a message on the server??

Comment: `0.0.0.0` indicates that it's listening on all interfaces, but you can't use `0.0.0.0` as the IP address to connect to. Use `127.0.0.1` to connect to localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Your server is running on localhost so you should use `127.0.0.1`.

Then for testing I would prefer using `netcat` or `telnet` for example: `telnet 127.0.0.1 3210` or for simple message sender you can use: `echo message > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/3210`